Why does my function hang when using multiprocessing in Python with Open3D?
I'm trying to use the multiprocessing module in Python to run a function that processes point clouds using the Open3D library. However, when I attempt to run this function in a separate process, it hangs and does not complete.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d

def foo():
    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]))    
    pcd.estimate_normals(search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.1, max_nn=30))
    print("normal", np.asarray(pcd.normals))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("RUN foo")
    foo()

    print("RUN foo with multiprocessing")
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
    p.join()

When I run the code, the function foo() executes correctly when called directly, but when I attempt to run it with multiprocessing, it hangs after starting the process.
**Versions**:
- numpy==1.24.2
- open3d==0.18.0
- python==3.10.15
- ubuntu==20.04


I couldn't find any solutions, so I came here.

Unable to replicate in Python 3.13.0 as there is no compatible distribution of open3d

@SIGHUP actually, that's why I specified my python version :)

Don't combine multiprocessing with anything that does its own parallelization; you end up spending all your time in context switches if it doesn't fail outright. You don't need multiprocessing when the libraries you call already do their own parallelization; it's all overhead and no benefit at that point.

(that is to say: multiprocessing is not a "make everything faster" magic bullet; it's a specialist tool for specialist situations, and when you use it inappropriately you make things worse)

@CharlesDuffy Agreed, but quick question: do you happen to know exactly why this happens, like what’s going on internally with the C code and OpenMP? I’m not gonna to use it in an weird scenario; just curious! Any resources would be great too.

@Odeaxcsh, nope, I'd need to reproduce with these specific libraries before I could give you a cause -- and it could even be different causes on machines with different hardware; on one you might end up paging memory out to swap, on another with more RAM the first bottleneck reached might be contention over GPU resources; on another with RAM and GPU resources it might be context-switch overhead slowing things down enough that it looks paused. Multiple ways to fail under stress, so there's not one easy answer for the mechanism.

One of the reason code hangs is due to multiprocess using fork and Open3D uses OpenMP library which has its own internal threads. See related Open3D issue and Python docs here:

Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic.

Try calling either
multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn") or
multiprocessing.set_start_method("forkserver")
before creating multiprocessing.Process object.
P.S. - The forkserver is not available on Windows but neither is fork. The code hang problem should not happen in Windows.
Also, similar problem is documented well on joblib documentation site.

Quick question: When using 'spawn' or 'forkserver', is the library being loaded repeatedly? I ran some tests, and the process start time increases significantly. If that's the case, I assume there's probably no gain in using open3d with multiple processes for small tasks.

@Odeaxcsh spawn creates process from scratch. I am not sure on forkserver, though. Will need to check. And yes, for very small workload, performance gain can be shadowed by process creation.

Thanks, I tested the forkserver as well, but the overhead was still present. In this case, with Open3D, the overhead is quite noticeable. On my relatively old laptop, importing Open3D takes about 1.2 seconds. I also looked into options to disable multithreading in Open3D, but it seems that none exist.

I actually just found out that you can set "OMP_NUM_THREADS" to 1 in the environment and everything works well. But of course some operations will be much slower. But anyway it is still an answer, it only took 2 hours and reading a lot of documents and going through some code.
